# Splitting String after Comma into Tuples Swift

Tags: swift

```
let input = "hello, world song"
```

I have an input string as above.

So i can easily use this partial string something like this

```
output.0 // hello
output.1 // world song
```

I tried something like this How to split a string by new lines in Swift but i could not exactly what i want.

Can someone write an extension for this please in a nice way?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to split it into a tuple, and not an array? Tuples have a fixed size, so they don't fit this problem very well.

Comment: I need to use for my coordinates in my case and i like to work with tuples, is that not possible ?

Comment: "for my coordinates" What does this mean?

Comment: Imagine you have an input of `"a, b, c, d"`, but you expected an output tuple with only 2 elements. Where are `c` and `d` supposed to go?

Comment: no matter other part for example : "Düsternstraße 18, 20355 Hamburg, Germany",

    -First Label:  Düsternstraße 18
    -Second Label: 20355 Hamburg, Germany

Comment: Ah, I see. I'll write up an answer.

Comment: Be careful with that kind of "arbitrary split". Your format might not be international. Except if of your your API states the format will always be the same (like a CSV).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an extension as below:

```
extension StringProtocol {

var tupleOfSplittedString: (String,String) {
    
    if !self.isEmpty {
        let splitted = self.split(separator: ",").map { String($0)}
        let firstPart = splitted[0]
        let otherPart = String(splitted[1...].joined().dropFirst())
        
        return (firstPart,otherPart)

    }

    return ("","")

    }
}

let input = "hello, world song"
let resultOfFirstPart = input.tupleOfSplittedString.0 // hello
let resultOfOtherPart = input.tupleOfSplittedString.1 // world song
```

Comment: `isSplittedTuple` sounds like it should return a boolean

Comment: It's a fixed size. Also you can use ```trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)``` instead of dropFirst.

Comment: @RajaKishan OP doesnt care about the rest of the string so no matter fix - i guess

Answer (score 3):

I would do something like this:

```
extension String {
    func splitAtFirst(_ separator: Character) -> (head: Substring, tail: Substring?) {
        guard let indexOfSeparator = self.firstIndex(of: separator) else {
            return (head: Substring(self), tail: nil)
        }

        let indexAfterSeparator = self.index(indexOfSeparator, offsetBy: +1, limitedBy: self.endIndex)!

        return (
            head: self[..<indexOfSeparator],
            tail: self[indexAfterSeparator...]
        )
    }
}
```

```
let (head, tail) = "abc, def, ghi".splitAtFirst(",")
print(head) // abc
print(tail as Any) // Optional(" def, ghi")
```

This returns Substrings, which gives you an efficient way to do a lot of processing on an input string without causing a bunch of copies along the way. Of course, you should promote these substrings to full on strings after you've finished processing them.

Answer (score 1):

This code uses the .components method to split a string by a substring. I have tested this, and it was successful, even if the String is blank (it returns ("", "") in that case)

Line 4 of this code is a bit hard to read, but you can split it up into multiple lines of code if you would like.

```
import Foundation
extension String {
    var tuple: (String, String) {
       return self.components(separatedBy: ",").count == 2 ? ((self.components(separatedBy: ",")[0], self.components(separatedBy: ",")[1] )) : ("", "")
    }
}
var input = "hello, world song"
print(input.tuple.0) //prints hello
print(input.tuple.1) //prints  world song
```